# Linq to Objects: filtering performance question

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects, performance

I was thinking about the way linq computes and it made me wonder:

If I write

```
var count = collection.Count(o => o.Category == 3);
```

Will that perform any differently than:

```
var count = collection.Where(o => o.Category == 3).Count();
```

After all, `IEnumerable<T>.Where()` will return `IEnumerable<T>` which doesn't implement `Count` property, so a subsequent `Count()` would actually have to walk through the items to determine the count which should cause extra time being spent on this.

I wrote some quick test code to get some metrics but they seem to beat each other at random. I won't put in the test code here initially, but if anyone requests, I'll get it in.

So, am I missing something?

Comment: They should be effectively the same as the list will only be enumerated over once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon Skeet says, both techniques will have to essentially do the same thing - enumerate the sequence while conditionally incrementing a counter when the predicate is matched. Any performance differences between the two should be slight: insignificant for almost all use-cases. If there is a token winner though, I would *think* it should be the first one, since from reflector it appears that the overload of`Count`that takes a predicate uses its own`foreach`to enumerate rather than the more obvious way of offloading the work to a  streaming a`Where`into a *parameterless*`Count`as in your second example. This means technique #1 is *likely* to have two *minor* performance benefits:

1. Fewer argument validation (null-tests etc.) checks. Technique #2's `Count` will also check if its (piped) input is an `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` , which it can't possibly be.
2. A single constructed enumerator vs two enumerators piped together (an additional state-machine has costs).

There is one minor in favour of technique #2 point though:`Where`is slightly more sophisticated in constructing an enumerator for the source-sequence; it uses a different one for lists and arrays. This *may* make it more performant in certain scenarios.

Of course, I should reiterate that I might be plain *wrong* about my analysis - reasoning about performance through static code analysis, especially when the differences are likely to be slight, is not a good idea. There is only one way to find out - measuring the execution times for your specific setup.

FYI, the source I reflected was from .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 3):

There won't be a lot in it, really - both forms will iterate over the collection, check the predicate against each item, and count the matches. Both approaches will stream the data - it's not like `Where` is actually building an in-memory list of all matches, for example.

The first form has one fewer (thin) layer of indirection in, that's all. The main reason for using it (IMO) is for readability/simplicity, rather than performance.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you are thinking here. At least, I think I do; `Count()` will look to see if `Count` is available as a property, and will simply return that if so. Otherwise, it has to enumerate the items to get its return value.

The version of `Count()` which accepts the predicate, though, will always cause the collection to be iterated, since it has to do it to see which ones match.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers make good points, consider also that if you break away into any Linq-To-X implementations that deferred execution (Linq to Sql being the primary), the Expression parameters used in these methods may cause different results.